# Play local video from code when dynamically change src Phonegap + javascript

Tags: jquery, cordova, video, autoplay

I'm have this issue when im try play (.play()) from javascript code my video tag, i'm using Phonegap and JQueryMobile.

This is my videoPlayer page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-reproduccion" data-theme="b">
 <div data-role="content">
  <video id="reproductor" autostart>
  </video>
 </div>
</div>
```

And this method is for change the src.

```
var videoPlayer = $('#reproductor');

  videoPlayer.bind('loadeddata', function(){
    console.log('Datos cargados');
  });

  videoPlayer.bind('ended', function(){
    console.log('Fin del video!');
  });

  videoPlayer.bind('canplay',function() {
    console.log("Can Play");
  });

  videoPlayer.src = listaVideos[indexVideo].ruta_local;
  videoPlayer[0].autoplay = true;
  videoPlayer[0].load();
  videoPlayer[0].play();
```

I only need when i change the src, automatically autoplay the video.

I put this code in this ways:

```
  videoPlayer.bind('loadeddata', function(){
    console.log('Datos cargados');
    videoPlayer[0].load();
    videoPlayer[0].play();
    });
```

Or:

```
videoPlayer.bind('canplay',function() {
    console.log("Can Play");
    videoPlayer[0].load();
    videoPlayer[0].play();
  });
```

But not works, i have to click the play on the video tag.

**NOTE:** I'm put this code in "onclick" event button and works. But i need this autoplay without any interaction from user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

https://github.com/simplec-dev/AndroidMediaGestureSetting/blob/99df9b5/README.md

This plugin do:

```
setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
```